# Creating a javascript object with initial values, how?

Tags: javascript

```
    objCar = function(values){
     this = values;
     race = function(){
      alert('car model:'+this.model+' car brand: '+this.brand+' was joined the race');
     };
    };

    car = new objCar({'brand':'ford','model':'fiesta'});
    car.race;
```

I want to objCar be started with a json values for example and that these values can be passed in constructor and after that i can call the race function that is created inside the constructor of objCar, is that possible? when i try to do this i receive it:

> invalid assignment left-hand side
>   error source line: [Parar neste erro]
>   this = values;

tnx.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Car(values) {
    var  _this = this;

    values = values || {}; // in case the argument is undefined.

    this.brand = values["brand"] || ""; // empty string for default brand
    this.model = values["model"] || ""; // empty string for default model

    this.race = function() {
        alert('car model: '+ _this.model + ' car brand: ' + _this.brand + ' has joined the race');
    }
}

var car = new Car({'brand':'ford','model':'fiesta'});

car.race();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written the function constructor all wrong. This should correct things:

```
function objCar(values) {
    this.race = function() {
        alert('car model: ' + values.model + ' car brand: ' + values.brand + ' was joined the race');
    };
};

var car = new objCar({
    brand: 'ford',
    model: 'fiesta'
});
car.race();
```

Comment: tnx guy, but the problem is that i need these values directly in object... like, i can create a var inside the object to hold the json passed as argument in constructor... but how to make this json attributes be directly inside the object? ex. i want to make something like: car.model  but i don't want to specific set var model in the constructor cause the values that comes from the json will be random... is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to copy all the properties from values into this. You cannot reassign what `this` is.

```
function Car(values) {

    for (var key in values) {
      this[key] = values[key];
    }

    this.race = function() {
        alert('car model: ' + this.model + 
              ' car brand: ' + this.brand + ' just joined the race');
    };
};

var car = new Car({
    brand: 'ford',
    model: 'fiesta'
});
car.race();
```

Here's another way to do it, which is more like what you were trying to do, 
that is to use the passed in object as `this`; http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/s3sap/

```
function Car() {
    this.race = function() {
        alert('car model: ' + this.model + 
              ' car brand: ' + this.brand + ' just joined the race');
    };
    return this;
};

var car = Car.apply({
    brand: 'ford',
    model: 'fiesta'
});
car.race();
```

Or yet another way, oh how I love JS OO and the million ways to do the same thing.

```
function Car() {
    this.race = function() {
        alert('car model: ' + this.model + 
              ' car brand: ' + this.brand + ' just joined the race');
    };
};

var car = {
    brand: 'ford',
    model: 'fiesta'
};
Car.apply(car);
```

And I think neither of these is the best way, I'd rather use the prototype instead of closure based object orientation. http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html